# How to decompress Html pages client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have this proxy code taken from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ajaxproxy.aspx) and created as an HttpHandler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        string url = context.Request["url"];
        string contentType = context.Request["type"];

        // no buffering as we want to save memory
        context.Response.Buffer = false;

        // beging getting content
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        { 

            // set content type if specified
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, contentType);
            }

            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; " +
               "en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");                
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "*/*");

            // get that data
            byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);

            if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected) return;

            // deliver content type, encoding and length as it
            // is received from the external url
            context.Response.ContentType = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"];

            string contentEncoding = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Encoding"];
            string contentLength = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentEncoding))
                context.Response.AppendHeader(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding.ToString(), contentEncoding);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentLength))
                context.Response.AppendHeader(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength.ToString(), contentLength);


            // transmit the exact bytes downloaded
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);


    }
}
```

I’ve mapped this Http module in IIS7 as a managed hanlder and in my plain Html page I’m using jQuery to call the proxy and put the results in an iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "a.RegularProxy",
        data: { url: 'http://example.org/test.html', type: "text/html" },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("iframe").contents().find('html body').html(data.toString());
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works fine when the page is nice and simple, however if the page is compressed (gzip, deflate) I need to find a way to **decompress it on the client side** and not within the proxy - the proxy's function is to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers do the decompression automatically, based on the HTTP headers.

I suspect what's happening is that the `WebClient` is automatically decompressing the response as it's received from the upstream server.  Your code then transmits the decompressed info to the client, but tells the client that the data is compressed.

There's no way, directly, to tell `WebClient` not to decompress.  You have to create derived `WebClient` class and override the `GetWebRequest` method.  In that method, you tell the `HttpWebRequest` not to decompress.  It'll look like this:

```
public class MyWebClient: WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest wr = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        wr.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None;
        return wr;
    }
}
```

Then, you use the `MyWebClient` in place of `WebClient`:

```
using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient)
{
    // do your thing here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case, for test purposes I added some additional code to do the decompression within the proxy - using a check on the headers. The html page not previously appearing now displays exactly as it should. This makes me believe that WebClient is not automatically decompressing the response before writing to the Context object.

Comment: I would recommend writing a test program on the client that lets you see the raw data coming from the proxy.  If you turn off the automatic decompression on the client, you can see the data exactly as it's passed.  That's the only way you'll know for sure what's happening.  Also, on the proxy, I would suggest writing the bytes that you receive to a file, and examine the contents.  That way you can know for sure what's going on.